# IIS 7 URL rewrite on WCF Service

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

**Question Edited for better understanding:**

I have a WCF service and any of my links look like :

`https://192.168.1.31/ContactLibrary2.0HTTPS/Service.svc/.....` .

I want to get rid  of the `Service.svc`. I installed URL Writer in IIS but i don't know how to work with it. I search a little bit and didn't find anything to help me with this particular problem.

```
Any idea ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are configuring the application hosted at `/ContactLibrary2.0HTTPS` directly (and not the website containing that directory, for example), you may add an exact match for:

```
rest/GetContact
```

with a rewrite url of:

```
Service.svc/rest/GetContact
```

Perhaps you wish to rewrite *every* action of Service.svc, however; then you would need a regular expression match for:

```
^rest/.*$
```

with a rewrite url of:

```
Service.svc/{R:0}
```

**UPDATE**

Assuming you also need to remove that string from the urls of your HTML pages, you would need to couple the aforementioned inbound rule with a new outbound rule, applied to the files you are interested in.

To do that, please:

1. add a new outbound rule to your website and give it a name;
2. add a new precondition with two rules (matching any of them):

   - `{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}` matches `text/html`
   - `{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}` matches `application/xhtml+xmll`
3. configure the rule to match the *response* scope, matching the content within **A** tags:

   - should match the pattern using a regular expression;
   - with this pattern: `^(.*)(/Service\.svc/)(.*)$`
   - case insensitive;
4. configure the action to be a *rewrite*, with this value: `{R:1}{R:3}`

Comment: It doesn't work. I change it to "rest/.*$" and the "Service.svc" doesn't get removed from the link.

Comment: So... Do you wish to change the links rendered by your own pages to strip the "Service.svc" portion of their urls? Please add some more details to your question then.

Comment: I created a new precondition with those 2 rules and a new outbound rule with your specifications. How can i test this ? if i type : https://192.168.1.31/ContactLibrary2.0HTTPS/Service.svc/rest/GetAllContactsWithParameters "Service.svc" doesn't get removed and if i doesn't put it there the link is no more valid. Ideas ?